# TypeScript, exhaustiveness check not working properly

Tags: typescript

Let's say we are writing DB model for `Post`, and because database stores everything as string we need to write `parse` function that would take raw DB object and cast it to proper `Post` interface.

To reproduce set `noImplicitReturns: true`

```
interface Post {
  id:   number
  text: string
}

function parse<K extends keyof Post>(k: K, v: any): Post[K] {
  switch(k) {
    case 'id':   return parseInt(v)
    case 'text': return v.toString()
  }
}
```

There are two errors in that code. First - it won't compile, it seems like TypeScript didn't realises that our code is correct and ask for `default` statement to be added to the `switch`.

The second error - it won't detect that you are checking against wrong value. The wrong code below would compile without errors

```
function parse<K extends keyof Post>(k: K, v: any): Post[K] {
  switch(k) {
    case 'id':   return parseInt(v)
    case 'text': return v.toString()
    case 'some': return v.toString() // <= error, no `some` key
    default: return ''               // <= this line is not needed
  }
}
```

There's even third error, TypeScript would allow to return wrong value for the key, this wrong code would compile

```
function parse<K extends keyof Post>(k: K, v: any): Post[K] {
  switch(k) {
    case 'id':   return parseInt(v)
    case 'text': return 2 // <= error, it should be string, not number
    default: return ''
  }
}
```

Are those TypeScript limitations or I'm dong something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `K` extends `keyof Post` doesn't mean `K` is `keyof Post`, so instead of using generic type `K`, you must use `keyof Post` to limit the potential values of `K`.

Secondly, the default option is forced if you set `"switch-default": true,` in your tsconfig.json. So set it to `false` then the issue will go away.

Thirdly, `Post[K]` or even `Post[keyof Post]` will return all the possible types of `Post` properties, so `number` is possible. Typescript doesn't force `Post[K]` to the type of its `K` property, unless you point out which `K` is. Otherwise you must define the mapping type, like type `A = ['id', numer] | [text', string]` and define `Post` as `[A[0]]: A[1]`

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for the reply, can you please also attach the fixed version of the `parse` function? I'm trying to implement this part `so instead of using generic type K, you must use keyof Post to limit the potential values of K` but it complains.

Answer (score 1):

Would this alternative appeals to you ?

```js
interface Post {
  id:   number
  text: string
}

type Parsers = {
    [k in keyof Post]: (v: any) => Post[k]
}

const parsers: Parsers = {
    id (v: any) {
        return parseInt(v)
    },
    text (v: any) {
        return v.toString(v)
    }
}

parsers.id('123') // number
parsers.text({}) // string

// In addition, adding extra parsers or returning a value of wrong type from a parser is type-checked.
```

---

Update

Making `Parser(renamed from Parsers)` type declaration generic and exploiting arrow function and contextual type inference, the code can be improved to:

```js
type Parser<T> = {
    [k in keyof T]: (v: any) => T[k]
}

interface Post {
  id:   number
  text: string
}

const parser: Parser<Post> = {
    id: v => parseInt(v),
    text: v => v.toString()
}
```